# Problema con formato de hora en javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, formato

Estoy enviando una fecha hacia en un campo de texto  y en la caja de texto recibe la fecha sin embargo me llega con formato `"Wed Jul 24 2019 12:54:17 GMT-0400 (hora estándar de tu zona)"` y necesito recibirla en `'Y-m-d'`

```js
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            disabledDates: ['2019-07-23'],
            formatDate:'Y-m-d',
            format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
            formatTime: 'H:i',
            step: (60),
            allowBlank: false,
            onSelectDate: function(dateText, inst) {$("input[name='datos']").val(dateText);}
            });
```

Creo que debo insertar el formato de fecha dentro del function pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general estas librerías utilizan [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) para hacer conversiones, en caso contrario podrías incorporar la librería, ya que es demasiado útil para trabajar con fechas, horas y formatos personalizados.

Te dejo un código que debería funcionar:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    disabledDates: ['2019-07-23'],
    formatDate:'Y-m-d',
    format: 'Y-m-d H:i',
    formatTime: 'H:i',
    step: (60),
    allowBlank: false,
    onSelectDate: function(dateText, inst){
        let formatedDate = moment(dateText).format("Y-m-d");
        $("input[name='datos']").val(formatedDate);
    }
};
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: ufff MUCHAS GRACIAS Jonathan! estaba pegado hace días!! no te puedo dar el like, tengo pocos puntos pero me salvaste!! gracias!!

Comment: Con mucho gusto @max